# Getting error while passing list<Wrapperclass> from lightning component to apex class

Tags: lightning

I need to pass `List<WrapperClass>` from lightning helper to apex class. Passing the list directly gave me the following error while iterating the list in apex.

> Error message: An internal server error has occurred Error ID:
>   1137130244-1625 (119852647)

So I tried to stringify the list in helper and passed it as a string .This time I am getting the below error in apex.

> QueryResult must start with '{'

Please find my code.

```
public class WrapperClass{
      @auraEnabled
      public Custom1__c custom1{get;set;}
      @auraenabled
      public Custom2__c custom2{get;set;}
      @auraenabled
      public List<Custom3__c> custom3List{get;set;}
      @auraenabled
      public List<String> currentList{get;set;}
}
```

Lightning helper:

```
       var action1 = component.get("c.saveCustomVolumes");
       {
       var customs = component.get("v.customIds");
       var tvList = component.get("v.wrapperList");
       var tvString = JSON.stringify(tvList);
       var baseYear = component.get("v.selectedYear");
       action1.setParams({
            "customList":customs,
            "tvString":tvString, // passing wrapper class as a String
            "baseYear":baseYear
        });
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {

                }
```

Apex class:

```
@auraenabled
public static saveCustomVolumes(List<String> customList,String tvString, String baseYear){
    List<WrapperClass> wrapList =          
 (List<WrapperClass>)JSON.deserialize(tvString,List<WrapperClass>.class); //This line gives the error QueryResult must start with '{'
}
```

Could anyone please help me with the issue.

Comment: You are getting internal server error in debug log or in Browser?

Comment: can you please paste the string, which you are passing to the controller.

Comment: I am getting Error message: An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1137130244-2045 (-1373094418) in the browser

Comment: String passing to controller--> [{"currentEpisodes":["15.00","","","","","","","","","","",""],"Schedules":[{"Title__c":"a0O0j0000061rzXXXX","Id":"a0r0j0000002esXXXX","Date__c":"2018-01-01","Count__c":15,"Year__c":"2018","Month__c":1}],"title":{"Id":"a0O0j0000061rzXXXX","Name":"Test"},"updatedEpisodes":["100","200","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100","110","120"]}]

Comment: Is the name of the JavaScript function calling the apex action same as the apex method name? If so, try renaming it.

Comment: @Ranga , I use different names for javascript helper and apex class method

Comment: Check in log as well, You might getting some exception there as well.

Comment: @Sindhuja string getting passed to apex doesn’t seem to have the right format as well. According to wrapper class, it should be an array containing objects. Each object needs to have custom1, custom2, list of custom3 objects and an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by forming JSON objects in javascript and adding it to a list and then passed this list to apex using JSON.stringify

Comment: Hi, Can you post the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JSON String passed into apex method must match the wrapper class format. For example, JSON string should be something like,

```
[{
    "custom1" : {
        "Id" : "a0O0j0000061rzXXXX",
        "Name" : "Test"
    },
    "custom2" : {
        "Id" : "a0r0j0000002esXXXX",
        "Title__c" : "a0O0j0000061rzXXXX"
    },
    "custom3List" : [{
            "Id" : "a0r0j0000002esXXXX",
            "Title__c" : "a0O0j0000061rzXXXX"
        },{
            "Id" : "a0r0j0000002esXXXX",
            "Title__c" : "a0O0j0000061rzXXXX"
        }
    ],
    "currentList" : ["ABC","DEF"]
}]
```